# WPF two-way Databinding not updating GUI when bound objects replaced

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that takes user input for a configuration settings before executing. The UI fields are databound to objects using two-way.

When I make a change in the gui the databound object updates as it should. If I change an **object property** in CS the GUI updates as it should.

Now the majority of the settings can be templated for different tasks. So I created several templates in JSON format. This JSON template is a dehydrated version of the configuration objects before execution.

So if a person chooses to use a template instead of entering all the settings I take the JSON, rehydrate, then wipe out the existing object with the deserialized json object. This is where I think it is breaking down, because the IPropertyNotify binding doesn't exist, or not properly connected to the json generated object. This code snippet shows the general idea. Full code will be below.

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rtfMasterContext>(confFile);
rtf_Master.WorkItemConfig = deserialized.WorkItemConfig;
rtf_Master.WorkspaceItemConfig = deserialized.WorkspaceItemConfig;
rtf_Master.BranchMergeConfig = deserialized.BranchMergeConfig;
```

Now if I change to a loop which updates the properties and does **NOT** break the INotify binding then the gui does update with the templated settings.

```
rtf_Master.WorkspaceItemConfig.SourceBranch = deserialized.WorkspaceItemConfig.SourceBranch;
```

As promised here is the full code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    rtfMasterContext rtf_Master = new rtfMasterContext();

   public MainWindow()
   {
     InitializeComponent();

     this.DataContext = rtf_Master;
   }
}
```

XAML Sample:

```
<Label>Source Branch</Label>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SourceBranch, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
```

Context and child properties snippets.

```
public class rtfMasterContext
{
    ....snip....
    public WorkspaceItemConfig WorkspaceItemConfig { get; set; }
    ....etc....
}


[DataContract]
public class WorkspaceItemConfig : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _sourceBranch;
    [DataMember]
    public string SourceBranch
    {
        get
        {
            return _sourceBranch;
        }

        set
        {
            _sourceBranch = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


}
```

So my question is how should I proceed. If I stick with updating just the properties is there a more elegant way then having one line like the above for each property, which would of course be tightly coupled. New configuration value then this would break if not updated.

Perhaps there is a way to replace entire objects as in the first snippet? If so then I'd imagine I would need to mark the IPropertyNotify to be serialized somehow?

Comment: Can you _snip_ less in the code posted? As far as I can see, the TextBox is expected to bind to a property "SourceBranch" of the "rtfMasterContext" class, that doesn't exist; it's present on "WorkspaceItemConfig" though (which might actually be your problem...).

Comment: The problem is that properties of `rtfMasterContext` does not notify property change. Implement INPC on `rtfMasterContext`.

Comment: @Mathew...RIGHT...so then when the the objects are swapped the rtfMasterContext see it as a property change!! Make your comment an answer so I can accept and upvote.